# How many days would B alone take to complete the work with given conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A can complete a piece of work $3$ times as fast as B.If A and B together can complete the work in $6$ days.

How many days would B alone take to complete the work?

options given:

a)$8$  b)$12$  c)$24$  d)$4$

My Approach:

Let A take x Days and B take $3x$ Days

A:B=$3$:$1$ Efficiency

Therefore, time taken is $x$:$3x$

Let A take x Days and B take $3x$ Days

A+B=$6$ days

So,Now A take x/x+$3$x=x/4x*$6$=$3$/$2$

Now B take $3x$/$4x$=$3$/$4$*$6$=$9$/$2$

This Approach is wrong i don't know why and i coulno't solve through other approaches.

Comment: What is the book answer?

Comment: @EmmadKareem It is 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the fraction of the work that $B$ does in one day. A does $3x$ in one day. They both do it in 6 days so $6(x+3x)=1$ and thus $x=1/24$. So $B$ needs $24$ days.

Answer (score 0):

As A is 3 time faster than B, so if A takes x days to complete the job, B will take 3x days for the same.
now 1/x + 1/3x = 1/6
(4/3x) = 1/6
x = 8 days 
so B will complete the job in = 3*8 = 24 days